# I found languages installed and I can't install one

Tags: joomla-3.x, language

First of all, I have 3 new languages installed on my Joomla!  I don't know how, I have no new users so i assume there is a vulnerability that allows languages to be installed somehow.  I was on 3.7.4 until I updated to 3.8.1 just now.  No idea how long the languages have been there.

I tried to uninstall Romanian and got this message:

**Warning
The Romnaro-RO extension is part of a package which does not allow individual extensions to be uninstalled.
The Romnro-RO extension is part of a package which does not allow individual extensions to be uninstalled.**

1. Does anyone have a suggestion as to how these languages got installed?
2. Does anyone know how I can uninstall Romanian?

Comment: `Warning The Romnaro-RO extension is part of a package` >> Check the ZIP files of all 3rd party extensions you're using to see if these language files exist within them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any extension can contain multiple languages within the zip file.  The language files probably came with an extension.  Look at the file names of the language files and that will tell you which extension installed them.

You may as well leave the language files in place, because each time you update the extension that installed them - they'll be replaced.

Language files are benign - they're just text files.